# Segmentation issue NASM

Tags: nasm

I'm working on conversions of c programs to NASM and I've been having issues with segmentation faults after the program runs. It will do what its supposed to do but will provide a segmentation fault message at the end of it.

The code is:

```
segment .data

out_less    db "Z is less than 20.", 10, 0
out_greater    db "Z is greater than 20.", 10, 0
out_equal    db "Z is equal to 20! Yeah Z!", 10, 0

segment .bss

segment .text

global     main
extern printf
ret
main:

    mov    eax, 10
    mov    ebx, 12

    mov    ecx, eax

    add    ecx, ebx    ;set c (ecx reserved)

    mov    eax, 3
    mov    ebx, ecx
    sub    ebx, eax    ;set f (ebx reserved)

    mov    eax, 12
    mul    ecx
    add    ecx, 10        ;(a+b*c) (ecx reserved)

    mov    eax, 6
    mul    ebx
    mov    eax, 3
    sub    eax, ebx
    mov    ebx, eax    ;(d-e*f) (ebx reserved) reassign to ebx to keep eax open for manipulation

    mov    eax, ecx
    div    ebx
    mov    ecx, eax
    add    ecx, 1        ;(a+b*c)/(d-e*f) + 1

    cmp    ecx, 20
    jl    less
    jg    greater
    je    equal

mov    eax, 0
ret

less:

    push    out_less
    call    printf
    ret
    jmp    end

greater:

    push    out_greater
    call    printf
    ret
    jmp    end

equal:

    push    out_equal
    call    printf
    ret
    jmp     end

end:

    mov    eax, 0
    ret
```

I'm not sure whats causing the fault because the program does actually run correctly any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update - this seems to work:

```
segment .data

out_less     db "Z is less than 20.", 10, 0
out_greater  db "Z is greater than 20.", 10, 0
out_equal    db "Z is equal to 20! Yeah Z!", 10, 0

segment .bss

segment .text

        global  main
        extern  printf

main:
        mov    eax, 10
        mov    ebx, 12
        mov    ecx, eax
        add    ecx, ebx    ;set c (ecx reserved)
        mov    eax, 3
        mov    ebx, ecx
        sub    ebx, eax    ;set f (ebx reserved)
        mov    eax, 12
        mul    ecx
        add    ecx, 10     ;(a+b*c) (ecx reserved)
        mov    eax, 6
        mul    ebx
        mov    eax, 3
        sub    eax, ebx
        mov    ebx, eax    ;(d-e*f) (ebx reserved) reassign to ebx to keep eax open for manipulation
        mov    eax, ecx
        div    ebx
        mov    ecx, eax
        add    ecx, 1      ;(a+b*c)/(d-e*f) + 1
        cmp    ecx, 20
        jl    less
        jg    greater
        jmp   equal

less:
        push    out_less
        call    printf
        add     esp,4
        jmp     exit

greater:
        push    out_greater
        call    printf
        add     esp,4
        jmp     exit

equal:
        push    out_equal
        call    printf
        add     esp,4
exit:
        mov    eax, 0
        ret

        end
```

Comment: That sadly didn't fix the fault. Thank you though for the advice.